# Attr_accessor for Subclass inside Parent Class

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm trying to figure out a way to dynamically generate subclasses based on a parent class. In my specific case I'd want to have attr_accessor for every instance variable, initialized in my Parent class and inherited on the SubClasses.
My classes are three different models representing three different tables in a DB.

"Record" is my parent class where I want to store and write all of my code.
"Post" and "User" are the Subclasses inheriting.

My code

```
class Record
 
  attr_reader :id
  # attr_accessor

  def initialize(**params)
    @id = params[:id]
    instance_variable_set("@#{params.keys[0]}", params.values[0])
    instance_variable_set("@#{params.keys[1]}", params.values[1])
    instance_variable_set(:@votes, params["votes"] || 0) if instance_of?(Post)
    # p self.title
  end
```

Want I want to achieve is setting attr_accessor as for example in my Subclass "Post" I want to call

```
post = Post.new(title: "New post", url: "some url")
puts post.title
```

I can access the title instance variable without raising a NoMethodError

Could someone guide me, or give me some hint?
Thanks

Comment: I am a bit confused. Do you just want to accept anything that is sent in via a `Hash` and create methods for that e.g. is `Post.new(title: "New post", url: "some url", left_hand_monkey_wrench: true)` a valid `Post` object and you can call `post.left_hand_monkey_wrench #=> true`? If this is your goal the implementation can be fairly simple, if not please explain your desire a bit more clearly.

Comment: @engineersmnky yes, it is exactly what I would like to achieve!

Comment: @engineersmnky could you please share a hint or help me? Really appreciate it

Comment: Why do you want to put all your code in Record? Referencing the child class from the parent like `instance_variable_set(:@votes, params["votes"] || 0) if instance_of?(Post)` is just all kinds of wrong. If `Post` has a specific attribute it should be definining it instead of putting everything into a god class.

Comment: I know what you are saying, but it is more a "style exercises". I'm new to ruby and programming and actually I'm trying to learning something new, so in this specific case it's an abstract exercise specific to this matter

Answer (score 0):

You're going about it backwards. A parent class should not have to know about or implement specific logic for its subclasses.

```
class Record
  attr_reader :id

  def initialize(**attributes)
    attributes.each do |key, value|
      send("#{key}=", value)
    end
  end
end
```

```
class Post < Record
  attr_accessor :title
  attr_accessor :votes
end
```

```
irb(main):066:0> Post.new(id: 1, votes: 10, title: "Hello World").title
=> "Hello World"
```

`attr_accessor` is just a metaprogramming convenience for defining methods so your accessor methods are inherited anyways. But if you're writing something like an Object Relational Manager you'll want to define your own macro method for defining attributes that lets you keep track of the attributes of a class:

```
module Attributes
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
    base.class_eval do
      @attributes ||= {}
    end
  end

  # assigns the passed attributes to the instance
  def initialize(**attributes)
    attributes.each do |key, value|
      send "#{key}=", value
    end
  end

  # gets all the attributes of an instance
  def attributes
    self.class.attributes.keys.each_with_object(Hash.new) do |key, hash|
      hash[key] = send(key)
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods
    # Inherits the attributes of the parent class
    def inherited(subclass)
      attributes.tap do |parent_attributes|
        subclass.class_eval do
          @attributes ||= {}.merge(parent_attributes)
        end
      end
    end

    # defines an attribute that is inherited
    def attribute(name, type = nil, **kwargs)
      @attributes[name] = { type: type }.merge(kwargs)
      attr_accessor name
    end

    def attributes
      @attributes
    end
  end
end
```

```
class Record
  include Attributes
  attribute :id, Integer
end
```

```
class Post < Record
  attribute :title, String
  attribute :votes, Integer
end
```

```
irb(main):101:0> Post.new(votes: 10, title: "Hello World").attributes
=> {:id=>nil, :title=>"Hello World", :votes=>10}
```

This stores the attribute definitions in a [class instance variable](https://www.codegram.com/blog/understanding-class-instance-variables-in-ruby/) which lets you attach "metadata" which opens up for features that you will want later such as typecasting, serialization and dirty tracking.

Comment: Given the simplicity (read naivety) of the desired implementation then it seems like `def initialize(**params); @attributes = params; end;` followed by either a `method_missing` look up or a simple `@attributes.each {|a| define_method(a) { @attributes[a]}; define_method("#{a}=") {|val| @attributes[a] = val}}` would do the trick